# Why Do I Get 'Undefined or Null Reference' Mid-Loop?

Tags: javascript, undefined-reference

I'm creating a JavaScript array using VBS. The code produced on the HTML page generates an error (as seen at the point in the code below). Why would this error appear here at the point of the third assignment? (I'm a relative beginner).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myArray = [[],[]];

    myArray[0][0] = "3";
    myArray[1][0] = "1";
    myArray[2][0] = "2";
    **Unable to set property '0' of undefined or null reference**
    myArray[3][0] = "4";

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You only defined 2 child arrays:

```
var myArray = [[],[]];
                ^  ^   ?  ?
                0  1   2  3
```

If you'd had `[[],[],[]]`, you'd have gotten the undefined warning on `myArray[3]` instead of `[2]`.

In longer terms, your original `myArray` definition could be written as:

```
var myArray = []; // define parent array
myArray[0] = []; // first child array
myArray[1] = []; // second child array;
```

and then you go off to the assignment part. When you try to assign to `myArray[2]`, you're in undefined territory, and get the warning.

Comment: Thanks Marc B. Your answer lead me in the right direction. I'm using the code from @mor posted July 21, '13, (I don't know how to show a link to it).

Comment: @RicardoX7, welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to upvote quality answers and accept the one that helped you the most